# Damage Resulted To The Car

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "result".  On the web, I found sentences along the lines of:

> 1. Damage ***resulted to*** the car.

But dictionaries say that the verb "*result*" should be used like the following:

> 2. Damage to the car ***resulted from*** carelessness.
> 3. Carelenesss ***resulted in*** damage to the car.

Is sentence 1 then poor usage?  What do native speakers think?

Answer (score 1):

**Result to** is frequent in legal and insurance contexts.

> Insurer will not be held liable for damage resulting **to** insured's
>   property **from** Acts of God, Acts of War or civil unrest, or
>   earthquake and other natural disasters.

**Result** licenses both **to-** and **from-** phrases.

Consider [this example](https://books.google.com/books?id=7g5IAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1079&dq=%22resulting%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_2KK-qfPNAhWBrB4KHaERAFQQ6AEIOTAG#v=onepage&q=%22resulting%20to%22&f=false).

Comment: Also *Damage to the car **resulted in** it being written off.*

Comment: The reason for its use in legal and insurance contexts is that the fact that the car was damaged in the process of some event is important, but it can be very hard to specify causailty ("The car was damaged by X").  Worth noting is that use of this phrasing makes your speech sound quite strange.  Its usually an indication to the listener that the speaker intends to treat a situation as a lawyer and every word choice matters.